# Outlook Office 365 : Refresh token failed to retrieve because "AADSTS70000" the provided value for the 'code' parameter is not valid

Tags: oauth, outlook, oauth-2.0, office365, access-token

In below code I can retrieve refresh token successfully from email@company.com email addresses. However, when I try to login with email@outlook.com it doesn't give the refresh token instead it returns this response.

Response:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "AADSTS70000: The provided value for the 'code' parameter is not valid. The code has expired.\r\nTrace ID: ...\r\nCorrelation ID: ...\r\nTimestamp: 2016-05-19 10:13:05Z",
  "error_codes": [
    70000
  ],
  "timestamp": "2016-05-19 10:13:05Z",
  "trace_id": "8cceb393-....",
  "correlation_id": "5227de8...."
}
```

Code:

```
 private async Task<string> GetRefreshRoken(string authCode, string onSuccessRedirectUri) {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
       {
          {"client_id", _clientId},
          {"client_secret", _clientSecret},
          {"code",authCode }, // what retreived from //https://login.microsoftonline.com/common with authroization.
          {"redirect_uri",  onSuccessRedirectUri}, //http://localhost:27592/Home/Authorize
          {"grant_type","authorization_code" }
       };
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token", content);
        var tokensJsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        dynamic token = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(tokensJsonString);
        return token.refresh_token;
    }
```

So I had googled with the error number and found http://www.matvelloso.com/2015/01/30/troubleshooting-common-azure-active-directory-errors/ page where the error describes:
[image]

Then I had changed my redirecting url to "http://localhost:27592/Home/Authorize/". Since I am using this https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/dotnet tutorial as a reference , now I cannot login with any other account.

[image]

Is there any good approach to retrieve refresh tokens for outlook account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For windows live id account, you will get error "*The provided value for the 'code' parameter is not valid. The code has expired.*" when using the authorization code twice.

The correct way to refresh the token is using refresh token ([v2.0 token reference > Refresh Token)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-tokens/).

First, ensure you have declare the scope "offline_access".

Then, you will get the access_token when acquire the token using grant_type=code (the first time you acquire the token).

Next, you need to use grant_type=refresh_token to refresh your access token.

[image]

Comment: Let me try and then get back to you on Tuesday... Thank you again for your help. I am currently on vacation.

Comment: After adding  "offline_access" in the scope it says  : API does not accept offline_access as a user-provided scope

Comment: I assume you were using Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, if so, openid and offline_access scopes are added by default. But from the code you post, I did not see you use that library.

Comment: Yes, currently I am using  Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory . Now the problem is it sometimes gives the refresh token and sometimes not.

Comment: To narrow down this issue, can you try the HTTP request way instead of using Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory. First, let's ensure the refresh token flow will work at your side. After that, we can discuss why the refresh_token does not returned sometimes in a new session.

Comment: Can you please point me to a url to use that http flow. I have my code here : https://github.com/aukgit/Google-Outlook-Calender-Integrate/blob/master/CalendarMvc/Modules/Calendar/Outlook/OutlookCalendarAccess.cs#L98